# Equation of pair of reflected straight lines given the equation of pair of incident straight lines

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

If $ax^2 + 2bxy + by^2 = 0$ represents a pair of lines, then find the combined equation of lines that can be obtained by reflecting these lines about the x-axis.

I know that this can be done by separating the lines from the given equation and then finding the reflected rays and then combining the reflected rays again, but I was wondering if there is a short way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reflection about the x-axis can be rapidly obtained substituting $y$ with $-y$. So you obtain $ax^2-2bxy+by^2$. Also note that, in this case, the new lines are symmetrical to the initial Iines with respect to the y-axis as well.

Comment: why not substituting $x$ with $-x$

Comment: In general, to reflect about the x-axis, you have to substitute $y$ with $-y$, not $x$ with $-x$. Your function is an exception because is symmetrical, so that changing the sign to either $x$ or $y$ gives the same result.